# iOS Webhook / Notification for Recurring Payment for AutoRenewable Subscriptions

Tags: ios

Is there a notification that iOS sends for autorenewable subscriptions when a recurring payment is processed and the subscription is extended? Is that what the RENEWAL webhook should be interpreted as?

Comment: See my answer into this Q: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50947948/server-to-server-pollling-auto-renewable-subscription/54440609#54440609

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I spoke to an Apple representative and they said that Apple only sends the notifications for the initial purchase. Subsequent renewals must be polled like a normal transaction.

RENEWAL is actually sent when there "is a lapse in service and a recovery by Apple's billing Retry Product."

This is the real answer and it is found NO WHERE on Apple's documentation. I hope this helps other people.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Did Apple say anything about INTERACTIVE_RENEWAL? According to the documentation, it is supposed to be sent for auto renewed subscription, but I assume from your answer that this event is not sent automatically and we need to poll instead.

Comment: Excellent article discussing this step by step how to handle auto renewing subs with iOS: https://medium.com/@AlexFaunt/auto-renewing-subscriptions-for-ios-apps-8d12b700a98f

Answer (score 3):

This what [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Subscriptions.html) says:

> Status Update Notifications
>
> A statusUpdateNotification is a server-to-server notification service
>   for auto-renewable subscriptions. A notification specifies the status
>   of a subscription at the time the notification is sent.
>
> To obtain up-to-date information as you process events, your app
>   should verify the latest receipt with the App Store. It is recommended
>   that you use the status update notification service along with receipt
>   validation to validate a user’s current subscription status and
>   provide them with service. See Receipt Validation Programming Guide
>   for information about receipt validation.
>
> To receive status update notifications, configure a subscription
>   status URL for your app in iTunes Connect. The App Store will deliver
>   JSON objects via an HTTP POST to your server for the key subscription
>   events listed in Table 6-3. Your server is responsible for parsing,
>   interpreting, and responding to all statusUpdateNotification posts.

It then continues below listing the conditions for a notification:

- **INITIAL_BUY** Initial purchase of the subscription. Store the latest_receipt on your server as a token to verify the user’s subscription status at any time, by validating it with the App Store.
- **CANCEL** Subscription was canceled by Apple customer support. Check Cancellation Date to know the date and time when the subscription was canceled.
- **RENEWAL** Automatic renewal was successful for an expired subscription. Check Subscription Expiration Date to determine the next renewal date and time.
- **INTERACTIVE_RENEWAL** Customer renewed a subscription interactively after it lapsed, either by using your app’s interface or on the App Store in account settings. Service is made available immediately.
- **DID_CHANGE_RENEWAL_PREFERENCE** Customer changed the plan that takes affect at the next subscription renewal. Current active plan is not affected.

So to answer you question: Yes, successful renewal means that Apple received the payment of your user (and that you will also be paid).

However, it's **not** sent to iOS but only to a server. You need to register a URL with Apple on which they will then POST these notifications. Your server and iOS app instance must then talk via your web API to get the app notified.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm set up with the iOS Sandbox environment, and I'm logging the various notifications that Apple sends for various test subscription purchases that I'm making. However, it's not clear to me that RENEWAL is indeed sent for recurring payments because the behavior in Sandbox doesn't match this.

Comment: Using a sanbox tester-account, the event `INITIAL_BUY` never arrives.

Answer (score 3):

You can use following steps to setup Server to Server Notifications:

- Sign in to App Store Connect and select your app.
- Navigate to the App Information section.
- Paste the API-URL into the "URL for App Store Server Notifications" field.
- Click "Save" at the top of the page.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, according to the documentation, RENEWAL is sent after an expired subscription is automatically renewed (note that this is different than INTERACTIVE_RENEWAL in that RENEWAL is triggered automatically by an auto-renew subscription expiring, rather than user action).

However, the Sandbox environment is slightly different (see "The Test Environment" in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Subscriptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH7-SW8)):

> The behavior of auto-renewable subscriptions differs between the testing environment and the production environment.
>
> In the testing environment, subscription renewals happen at an
>   accelerated rate, and auto-renewable subscriptions renew a maximum of
>   six times per day. This enables you to test how your app handles a
>   subscription renewal, a subscription lapse, and a subscription history
>   that includes gaps. See Testing Auto-Renewable Subscriptions in the
>   In-App Purchase Configuration Guide for iTunes Connect to learn about
>   the subscription durations for testing.
>
> Because of the accelerated expiration and renewal rates, a
>   subscription can expire before the system tries to renew the
>   subscription, leaving a small lapse in the subscription period. Such
>   lapses are also possible in production for a variety of reasons—make
>   sure your app handles them correctly.

So, for each productId you have, it will only auto-renew up to six times a day in Sandbox. After that, you will stop receiving RENEWAL notifications from Apple.